# OpenStack Server Instances have internet access, but they are unable to access the internal network

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, openstack, nova-network

I'm running an OpenStack Grizzly release with a Nova-Network configuration. [No Quantium]. My network is setup as follows:

OpenStack Box (10.10.13.xx network)->OpenStack Internal Network (192.168.0.xx)

My openstack instances can access the internet and see each other [within the 192 network] However they cannot access anything within the 10.10.13.xx netowrk. They have a floating IP which gives them an identity on the 10.10.13.xxx network [which is needed].

Is there a way that they can see and route to the items in the 10.10.13 network?